# Reverse a python string and remove the symbols

Tags: python

```py
def reverse_letter(string):
    result = ''
    
    for char in string:
        if char.islower():
            result = char + result
    
    return result
```

This is a program meant to reverse the string and remove the symbols from the string.
I am unable to understand the solution to the problem.
How does the above code reverse the string?

Comment: Do you understand what `char + result` means?

Comment: I'd suggest to print the values in between to see what happens. Just before the `result = char...` line, put a `print(result, char, char+result)` and see what happens.

Comment: but you are missing a `def` at the beginning of the code snippet

Comment: No. Can you explain?
I would be extremely thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens in the result = result + char portion of code. It's just a matter of if you want "char" added to the left or right side of result.

Here is the code when I switch the addition portion, "it will appear normally."

```
string_one = 'daniel'

def reverse_letter(string):
    result = ''

    for char in string:
     if char.islower():
        print(result)
        result =  result + char

    return result


print("Final Result:",reverse_letter(string_one))
```

Output

```
d
da
dan
dani
danie
Final Result: daniel
```

Original Code

```
string_one = 'daniel'

def reverse_letter(string):
    result = ''

    for char in string:
     if char.islower():
        print(result)
        result =  char + result

    return result


print("Final Result:",reverse_letter(string_one))
```

Output

```
d
ad
nad
inad
einad
Final Result: leinad
```

Check out [String Concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp) if you are still confused.